# Isolated high voltage FET switch

Tags: mosfet, opto-isolator, isolation

I want to design an isolated FET switch. The schematic is shown below.

The optoisolator datasheet is [here](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/h11f3m-d.pdf).

I have never designed this kind of circuit before. Can someone advise if this is correct in terms of the design?

This optoisolator is only been used to switch the MOSFET three times a day, hence it is not switching at high frequencies

The output current will range from 3A to 8A MAX.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyTNKL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Do you really need 50 mA to drive D1? What switching speed is required? What output current is being controlled/switched?

Comment: @Andyaka please see the post, I have edited the question

Comment: The 1N4148 output diode is likely to fail on any back-emf from wiring/load. The opto-diode drive current is too high I reckon. The data sheet hints at a current of around 16 mA.

Comment: @Andyaka why would the drive current be a problem? A MOSFET is voltage controlled.

Comment: Maximum operating temperature is 100 degC so, I'd always seek to keep emitter diode power dissipation to a reasonable figure and not close to the absolute maximum. It's not a big device and self warming in a high ambient temperature could be problematic. Dark current also runs out of control as the device warms past about 60 degC. Why waste power too. Aren't we all expected to be greener these days?

Comment: Another thing to consider is the breakdown voltage: It's specified as ±30V. In your application, when the isolator is off (i.e. no LED current) full 54V will drop across the detector, and possibly will break it down.

Answer (score 3):

The 867R (R4) limits the LED current at ~50mA, but the device ratings are given for 16 mA. So the R4 can be increased to 2k7, and its power rating should be at least 1W.

And, as I stated in my comment above, the 54V will break the detector FET down.

I'd suggest the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMcdH6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

10V is generated from 54V using a current limiter resistor and a Zener. And the detector is connected in series with this 10V source and MOSFET. When there's no LED current this series resistance can be as high as 300M, basically open circuit, and the maximum voltage across it will be 10V which is safe for the device.

D4 is there to protect the MOSFET in case the power is applied in reverse polarity (the body diode will be forward biased and a very high current will flow through the MOSFET and D3, and nothing will stop it). Since the load current will always flow through it, it should be selected carefully (current and voltage ratings). You may want to move the fuse to a more relevant location for such event, if you don't want to place D4.